# Hibernate reset id to 1 after deleting all records from Entity

Tags: hibernate

I've POJO class **Orders**

```
package POJO;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Orders 
{
    @Id
    private int oid;
    private int cid;
    private Date date;
    private float igst;
    private float cgst;
    private float sgst;
    private float roundoff;
    private int total;
    private int gTotal;

    public Orders(int oid, int cid, Date date, float igst, float cgst, float sgst, float roundoff, int total, int gTotal) {
        this.oid = oid;
        this.cid = cid;
        this.date = date;
        this.igst = igst;
        this.cgst = cgst;
        this.sgst = sgst;
        this.roundoff = roundoff;
        this.total = total;
        this.gTotal = gTotal;
    }

}
```

Suppose 10th record oid is 10 and if I deleted all records from Entity and added new record then it get oid 11. I want to reset it to 0 after deleting all records. How can I do it?

I'm using database MYSQL 5.5

Comment: please specify the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

or use TRUNCATE instead of delete:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE t1;
```

Truncate resets the auto_increment where delete doesn't